# React - How to iterate over dictionary in render method using JSX?

Tags: ecmascript-6, reactjs

I'm learning React and have set up a small test app that makes an Ajax call that returns a JSON object that I want to iterate over in the return method of my component. I've tried everything I can think of and have googled this, but like an hour later I'm still stumped.

Here is what I have...

```
render() {
  const { vals } = this.state;
  return (
    <div>
      {/* note that this correctly outputs the value of vals[key]: {vals['key']} */}
      Object.keys({vals}).map((key, index) => ( 
        <p key={index}> this is my key {key} and this is my value {vals[{key}]} </p> 
      ))
    </div>
  )
}
```

What am I doing wrong here? Any recommendations on a good reference for ES6/JSX? I've been struggling with simple things, with no good way to look up this info.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

`{vals}` extracts out the `vals` property from an object. Hence `Object.keys({vals})` is incorrect as `vals` is already an object. Likewise, it should be `{vals[key]}` instead of `{vals[{key}]}`.

```
render(){
  const {vals} = this.state;  // Essentially does: const vals = this.state.vals;
  return (
    <div>
      {
        Object.keys(vals).map((key, index) => ( 
          <p key={index}> this is my key {key} and this is my value {vals[key]}</p> 
        ))
      }
    </div>
  )
}
```

If `vals` is an object containing `{ a: 1, b: 2}`, `Object.keys(vals)` will get you `['a', 'b']` and in the first iteration of the map, `key` will be `'a'` and to access the value, do `vals[key]` which is essentially `vals['a'] => 1`.

I think you are confused by the Object destructuring syntax. It's really quite simple as it's just syntactic sugar over ES5 JavaScript (most ES6 is just sugar). Have a read at [MDN's docs on Destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) to understand it better.

Comment: OK, cool I see now. I was definitely confused there - I guess I'm not sure where ES6/JSX start/end. I will need to do some reading up on both. Thank you for the great explanation.